# Intended effect of sum over a python map

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython

`sum(map(len, ["a", "aa", "aaa"]))` gives me a `map` instead of a number.

I expected this to give the same result as `sum(len(thing) for thing in ["a", "aa", "aaa"])` (that is `6`).

I see that `list(sum(map(len, ["a", "aa", "aaa"])))` returns me `[1, 2, 3]`, as if the `sum` had no effect.

I assume there is a reason for such a behaviour. Is there an intended use case for this?

Comment: `np.sum(list(map(len, ["a", "aa", "aaa"])))` gives 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that I was working in `ipython` and that the builtin `sum` function was masked by "function sum in module numpy.core.fromnumeric" (according to `help(sum)`). I suspect an effect of having issued the command `%pylab`.

`__builtin__.sum(map(len, ["a", "aa", "aaa"]))` gives the expected `6`.

Comment: Yes, the Python `sum` accepts an iterable or map, but the `numpy.sum` tries to turn it into an array first.  The default behavior of `%pylab` is to do `from numpy import *`.  I have that turned off in my `ipython` config file, so numpy code does not shadow builtins.

Comment: Aha!  The worst part is that it still syntax highlights it as a built-in when it's not.